# Remapping Keyboard xmodmap

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to remap some keys on this keyboard. It is missing the control key, and I have attempted to use xmodmap, but without success.

For example, when I check the button settings using xev, it shows me 67  F1 key. I then remap it with the command 'keycode 67 = Control_L'. After this, xev correctly displays the settings button as Control_L. However, when I use the nano editor, pressing the settings button along with 'x' doesn't exit as expected with Control + X.

[image]